# Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $C$ , show that the function $g (z) = f(\overline{z})$ Is not holomorphic in any point

Tags: complex-analysis

help with this excercise

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in  $C$ such that $f´(z) \neq 0$ all $z$, show that the function $g (z) = f(\overline{z})$
Is not holomorphic in any point

---

How is $g(z)$ ?

$f(x-iy)=u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)$??

Comment: If $f' \neq 0,$ then near any point there is a neighbourhood where $f$ is an analytic diffeomorphism.

Comment: Another a bit different proof from the one I wrote below is writting $f$ as a power series, making the substitution of $z$ by $\bar z$ and taking limits in different directions.

Comment: I think, write the Cauchy Riemann equations for $f(z)$ and $f(\bar{z})$, and maybe  deduce $f'=0$ for contradiction

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}=0$ implies that $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis implies that $f$ is locally invertible with differentiable inverse; if $g$ where indeed differentiable at some point, then the composition of $g$ with the (local) inverse of $f$ would be differentiable and equal to the function $z \mapsto \bar z$ which is differentiable nowhere, an absurd. QED